# VIM: "^F" appears at the end of a line (after typing Enter)

Tags: vim

[image: For example]

The encoding of the strange character is '\x06'.
Anyone can give some tips?

Thanks.

Comment: Does it happen with `vim -u NONE`?

Comment: have you tried `:set list` and `:set nolist`?

Comment: @Leroy I tried, it didn't make any difference though

Comment: @FDinoff No. There is a complicated .vimrc in my homedir. But I'm not familiar with the syntax of VIM. I just wonder why the "^F"(\x06) appears.

Comment: Try with `vim -u NONE -N` and see if it reproducible. Also check your mappings Press `:imap <C-V><Enter><Enter>` Also please check the [faq](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.5)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Solved. The debug tip is really helpful! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Thanks for the helpful tips!

The debug tip [faq25](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.5) helped me.

I found the configuration line in .vimrc to blame. Something like:

`inoremap <expr><CR>  (pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>":'') . "\<C-f>\<CR>"`

I don't understand why putting the "^F" to the tail of a line, I change it to:

`inoremap <expr><CR>  (pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>":'') . "\<CR>"`

And it solved the problem.